# override the User type or DefaultUser type in next-auth

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-auth

I am currently using next-auth(v4.24.3) to implement login functionality. I am using the CredentialsProvider along with my own API server to verify usernames and passwords. In the authorize function, I want to return my custom-defined user object.

I have added a `types/next-auth.d.ts` file in the project and declared the User type: (it just only has one property 'id')
[next-auth.d.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ChgK.png)

but, In the authorize function of the CredentialsProvider, user data can still have additional properties:
[CredentialsProvider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQ6oV.png)

The returned user data should only have the 'id' property.

I have also tried declaring DefaultUser in the `types/next-auth.d.ts` file, but it didn't work.

How do I customize the User type~?